# Is there a Fate LARP?

Tags: game-recommendation, fate, larp

I was wondering whether there is a LARP implementation of Fate Core or Accelerated anywhere? I did take a look at Fate SRD, but they don't seem to mention that. I am really curious at this point, since simple, RPS-compatible mechanics seem like a good candidate for a non-physical combat resolution, but the business of keeping track of Fate Points and Aspects is somewhat more difficult.

Is there an official or fan-made resource available freely anywhere? If more than one exist, which would be the most tested, robust and player-friendly of them all, assuming no-touch, abstracted combat is required?

Comment: This question is asking if an implementation exists.  That seems like a factual request.

Comment: @KieranMullen you could retag to [tag:content-identification]

Comment: @Trish Thank you for the suggestion.  I find the "game-recommendation" tag problematic in general and am reading on its proper use.  I changed the tag but the change didn't stick?

Comment: I definitely think this is a game (or at least *content*) recommendation question. It explicitly asks for a resource that is freely available and about a specific thing, which is, to me, asking for a recommendation. Either way though, it is a shopping question and should/will be closed

Comment: @KieranMullen it was an old tag that is no longer allowed. we try to get rid of the last remnants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's one in playtest now, branded as **[Dresden Lives](http://www.evilhat.com/home/dresden-lives/).** The last iteration I saw, run at the Double Exposure conventions in New Jersey, used the Deck of Fate as part of its resolution mechanic, and the description lists conversion from the DFRPG to these new Live-Action Rules.

Comment: Evil Hat's work on Dresden Lives was unfortunately cancelled in August 2015: [The End of Dresden Lives — Evil Hat](https://www.evilhat.com/home/the-end-of-dresden-lives/) According to that announcement the project has been taken over by Phoenix Outlaw, but I can find no information on their site about its status.